# Why do consumers decrease the producer's performance

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, executorservice, producer-consumer

I'm currently trying to increase the performance of my software by implementing the producer-consumer pattern. In my particular case I have a producer that sequentially creates Rows and multiple consumers that perform some task for a given batch of rows.

The problem I'm facing now is that when I measure the performance of my Producer-Consumer pattern, I can see that the producer's running time massively increases and I don't understand why this is the case.

So far I mainly profiled my code and did micro-benchmarking yet the results did not lead me to the actual problem.

```
public class ProdCons {

    static class Row {
        String[] _cols;

        Row() {
            _cols = Stream.generate(() -> "Row-Entry").limit(5).toArray(String[]::new);
        }
    }

    static class Producer {

        private static final int N_ITER = 8000000;

        final ExecutorService _execService;

        final int _batchSize;

        final Function<Row[], Consumer> _f;

        Producer(final int batchSize, final int nThreads, Function<Row[], Consumer> f) throws InterruptedException {
            _execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
            _batchSize = batchSize;
            _f = f;
            // init all threads to exclude their generaration time
            startThreads();
        }

        private void startThreads() throws InterruptedException {
            List<Callable<Void>> l = Stream.generate(() -> new Callable<Void>() {

                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    return null;
                }

            }).limit(4).collect(Collectors.toList());
            _execService.invokeAll(l);
        }

        long run() throws InterruptedException {
            final long start = System.nanoTime();
            int idx = 0;
            Row[] batch = new Row[_batchSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < N_ITER; i++) {
                batch[idx++] = new Row();
                if (idx == _batchSize) {
                    _execService.submit(_f.apply(batch));
                    batch = new Row[_batchSize];
                    idx = 0;
                }
            }
            final long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
            _execService.shutdownNow();
            _execService.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            return time;
        }
    }

    static abstract class Consumer implements Callable<String> {

        final Row[] _rowBatch;

        Consumer(final Row[] data) {
            _rowBatch = data;
        }

    }

    static class NoOpConsumer extends Consumer {

        NoOpConsumer(Row[] data) {
            super(data);
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            return null;
        }
    }

    static class SomeConsumer extends Consumer {

        SomeConsumer(Row[] data) {
            super(data);
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            String res = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                res = "";
                for (final Row r : _rowBatch) {
                    for (final String s : r._cols) {
                        res += s;
                    }
                }
            }

            return res;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final int nRuns = 10;
        long totTime = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nRuns; i++) {
            totTime += new Producer(100, 1, (data) -> new NoOpConsumer(data)).run();
        }
        System.out.println("Avg time with NoOpConsumer:\t" + (totTime / 1000000000d) / nRuns + "s");

        totTime = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nRuns; i++) {
            totTime += new Producer(100, 1, (data) -> new SomeConsumer(data)).run();
        }
        System.out.println("Avg time with SomeConsumer:\t" + (totTime / 1000000000d) / nRuns + "s");
    }
```

Actually, since the consumers run in different threads than the producer, I would expect that the running time of the producer is not effected by the Consumer's workload. However, running the program I get the following output

#1 Thread, #100 batch size

Avg time with NoOpConsumer: 0.7507254368s

Avg time with SomeConsumer: 1.5334749871s

Note that the time measurement does only measure the production time and not the consumer time and that not submitting any jobs requires on avg. ~0.6 secs.

Even more surprising is that when I increase the number of threads from 1 to 4, I get the following results (4-cores with hyperthreading).

#4 Threads, #100 batch size

Avg time with NoOpConsumer: 0.7741189636s

Avg time with SomeConsumer: 2.5561667638s

Am I doing something wrong? What am I missing? Currently I have to believe that the running time differences are due to context switches or anything related to my system.

Comment: Main reason - this isn't a Consumer/Producer pattern. This is just a naive fork/join.

Comment: In fact, my explanation isn't correct: I misread the code, so I'll just remove it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, you are right. It's not a Consumer/Producer pattern, I'm sorry for the misleading title!

Comment: @JBNizet I think you're right - the code just splits a bunch of tasks across some threads. There is no producer consumer; unless you count the `ExecutorService` itself. What am I missing?

Comment: I had the feeling that the measurement stopped after the tasks had all been executed, but it doesn't. And the thread pool uses an unbounded queue, so the measurement looks correct: it measures how much time it takes to produce the tasks and submit them to the executor. So I guess Matt's explanation is the right one.

Comment: Hmmm - @EarlHickey try concattenating strings correctly; using a `StringBuffer`. If the others are right then the vast garbge produced by the `String` concatenation is what is essentially bogging down your application. Perhaps also limit the size of the `ExecutorService` queue and use a [caller runs policy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html) to apply backpressure.

Comment: @BoristheSpider for me a ExecutorService is a Consumer. That's why I called it producer consumer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thx 4 your input. This is just some toy example, reproducing the problem I'm facing. Looking closely at the SomeProducer outer loop, you'll see that these 1000 iterations are totally useless. Thx anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads are not completely isolated from one another.

It looks like your `SomeConsumer` class allocates a lot of memory, and this produces garbage collection work that is shared between all threads, including your producer thread.

It also accesses a lot of memory, which can knock the memory used by the producer out of L1 or L2 cache.  Accessing real memory takes a lot longer than accessing cache, so this can make your producer take longer as well.

Note also that I didn't actually verify that you're measuring the producer time properly, and it's easy to make mistakes there.

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense. Thanks for you quick response!